# How to convert the dataframe to a desired format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm looking to convert the dataframe to particular format.

The example dataframe is as follows:

```
Col1
a
b
c
```

I want to convert the above dataframe to following format by splitting into two columns:

```
Col1  Col2
a      a
a      b
a      c
b      b
b      c
c      c
```

I am trying to get all the combinations of the `Col1` column.

Comment: what's the logic?

Comment: @sammywemmy He wants the combinations

Answer (score 3):

You could try [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as comb
df = pd.DataFrame(list(comb(df['Col1'], 2)), columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2
0    a    a
1    a    b
2    a    c
3    b    b
4    b    c
5    c    c
>>>
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to @QuangHoang's comment, he mentioned that for higher versions (Quang Hoang has 1.1.4), you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(comb(df['Col1'], 2), columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

Without the `list(...)`. Whereas for lower versions you get:

```
TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator
```

Comment: I think just `pd.DataFrame(comb(df['Col1'], 2), columns=['Col1','Col2'])` would work.

Comment: @QuangHoang Oh yeah! that's right! edited mine, also upvoted your answer :) it's nice

Comment: @QuangHoang Only thing is that I still have to keep the `list(...)`, otherwise it gives: `TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator`

Comment: My Pandas `1.1.4` accepts an iterator. So `comb` works without wrapping around `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a cross merge:

```
df['key'] = 1

df.merge(df,on='key').query('Col1_x<=Col1_y').drop(['key'],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Col1_x Col1_y
0      a      a
1      a      b
2      a      c
4      b      b
5      b      c
8      c      c
```